# Redirect "virtual folder" to private folder using .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have trouble understanding the rewrite rules. I've tried a couple, but none seems to work.

I have a folder let's say in root/private/images/ that I want to be accessed using http://website/private_images/. My website is being served from root/public/, which should be where the .htaccess file is.

I would need something like this I guess (which doesn't work):

```
RewriteRule private_images/(.*) ../private/images/$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, because I'm doing something like you do and it works perfectly on my website (not released yet sorry you can't see it).

Here's how I do it:

```
# ...test if file exists in partner dir :
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../partnerdir/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
# file exists => rewrite + end :
RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../mypath/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

Tell me if it works.

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

May I ask you to add the rewritelog in your question?

Comment: This `RewriteRule  (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../mypath/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]` gives me back a "`BAD REQUEST`" (Apache 2.4), any idea why? (`mypath` is private in my configuration as in "not accessible from the internet")

Comment: Try so see the log files, and enable tracelog, and see what's inside to see how your path is "converted" by the rewrite rule

Comment: It's converted like so: `/Users/eightyfive/Sites/mysite.com/public/../my_private_folder/the_image_I_want_to_display_instead.jpg`. It may not be possible to output content that is not visible to the web (security reasons?)? If not it is definitely an error in my config. I will investigate further, thx for your help.

Comment: just try to see if the file exists, by typing "`ls -al thepath`". If it says "file does not exits" you'll solve your problem very fast **`:^)`**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason this doesn't work is that Apache interprets the second argument as a URL, but it can't resolve `../` relative to the root of your site.

The proper way to handle this setup is to put the lines

```
Alias /private_images /path/to/root/private/images
<Directory /path/to/root/private/images>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in your virtual host configuration.

If you don't have access to the virtual host configuration, you can put

```
RewriteRule /private_images(/.*) /path/to/root/private/images$1
```

in the `.htaccess` file.